# How can pass path of dicom file at cornerstone library and display it?

Tags: javascript, html, dicom, cornerstone

I want to display a Dicom image from my web site. So I have find cornerstone library to do this.

So this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- twitter bootstrap CSS stylesheet - included to make things pretty, not needed or used by cornerstone -->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="cornerstone.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="page-header">
        <br>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" id="selectFile" >
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div style="width:512px;height:512px;position:relative;color: white;display:inline-block;border-style:solid;border-color:black;"
         oncontextmenu="return false"
         class='disable-selection noIbar'
         unselectable='on'
         onselectstart='return false;'
         onmousedown='return false;'>
        <div id="dicomImage"
             style="width:512px;height:512px;top:0px;left:0px; position:absolute">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>


<!-- jquery - currently a dependency and thus required for using cornerstoneWADOImageLoader -->
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- include the cornerstone library -->
<script src="cornerstone.min.js"></script>

<!-- include the dicomParser library as the WADO image loader depends on it -->
<script src="dicomParser.min.js"></script>

<!-- include the cornerstoneWADOImageLoader library -->
<script src="cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/cornerstoneFileImageLoader.js"></script>
<!-- jpeg 2000 codec -->
<script src="jpx.min.js"></script>

<script>


    $(document).ready(function() {

        var element = $('#dicomImage').get(0);
         cornerstone.enable(element);

        // Listen for the change event on our input element so we can get the
        // file selected by the user
        $('#selectFile').on('change', function(e) {
            // Add the file to the cornerstoneFileImageLoader and get unique
            // number for that file
            var file = e.target.files[0];
            alert("cambio il file");

            var index = cornerstoneFileImageLoader.addFile(file);

            // create an imageId for this image
            var imageId = "dicomfile://" + index;
            // load and display this image into the element
            var element = $('#dicomImage').get(0);
            cornerstone.loadImage(uriImageDesktop).then(function(image) {
                cornerstone.displayImage(element, image);
            });

        });

    });

</script>
</html>
```

With this code, I can display a single HTML page with a File Chooser. With this component, I can navigate into my pc then the library load a Dicom image.

Now I want to pass from the URL a path of my Dicom image.

So I'm trying to do this

```
var uriImageDesktop = "C:\Users\michele\Desktop\deflate_tests\image";
            // load and display this image into the element
            var element = $('#dicomImage').get(0);
            cornerstone.loadImage(uriImageDesktop).then(function(image) {
                cornerstone.displayImage(element, image);
            });
```

for the moment I wirte static dicom image but it not found.

So the question is, how can I pass a path from my dicom file and then display it?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the image loader part here. Cornerstone requires an image loader to convert your link to an image object readable by cornerstone. If you look at [cornerstone's github repo](https://github.com/cornerstonejs), you will find two image loaders. The WADO image loader can be used to read DICOM files. You will have to build a backend to serve the DICOM files though since the browser won't be able to access server files. 
Given you have a uri to access the DICOM file:

```
import * as cornerstone from "cornerstone-core"
import * as cornerstoneWADOImageLoader from "cornerstone-wado-image-loader"
cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.external.cornerstone = cornerstone

const uriServed = "http://xxx/deflate_tests/image"
const element = $('#dicomImage').get(0);
cornerstone.loadImage("wadouri:" + uriServed).then(image => {
  cornerstone.displayImage(element, image);
 });
```

**NB**: if you do't have npm, just link to the .js files as scripts instead of importing (or you can import them too in ES6+)

Comment: Could you please help me with the JPG files, I am using below code, and no progress for me, I am new to it
`cornerstoneWebImageLoader.external.cornerstone = cornerstone;`  
 `const jpgImage = 'example://C/Med/MedSampleApplication/src/assets/images/Scr.jpg';`
`const element = document.querySelector('.image-canvas');`
`cornerstone.enable(element);`
`cornerstone.loadImage(jpgImage).then(function(image) {`
`cornerstone.displayImage(element, image)`
`});`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the URI format is invalid. The example does not contain a scheme. Something like

```
file://c:/Users/user/Desktop/images/image.dcm
```

may work better.